# Scroll works properly only for the first element

Tags: jquery

I need to do something like simple vertical carousel. On `hover` and `scroll` I need to scroll inner `ul` to the next or previous `li` element (it depends on scroll direction), change class `current` for current element and classes `prev` and `past` for previous and next elements accordingly.

HTML

```
<div id="scroll">
    <ul>
        <li style="background: red;"></li>
        <li style="background: green;"></li>
        <li style="background: yellow;"></li>
        <li style="background: blue;"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$.fn.scroll = function () {
var $this = $(this);
var $list = $(this).find('ul');
var $lis = $list.find('li');
var count = $lis.length;
var direction,
currentSlidePosition;

$this.addClass('scroll');
$list.addClass('slides-list');
$lis.addClass('slide');
$lis.filter(':first').addClass('current');
$lis.filter(':not(:first)').addClass('past');

var scrollHeight = $lis.eq(0).height();

function gotoSlide(direction) {
    currentSlidePosition = $lis.filter('.current').index();

    if ((direction === 1 && currentSlidePosition === 0) || (direction === -1 && currentSlidePosition === count - 1)) {
        return;
    }

    $lis.removeClass('current');
    $lis.eq(currentSlidePosition - direction).removeClass('past prev').addClass('current');
    $lis.filter('.current').prevAll().addClass('prev');
    $lis.filter('.current').nextAll().addClass('past');

    $list.animate({
        scrollTop: (direction === -1) ? scrollHeight : -scrollHeight
    }, {
        duration: 300
    });
}

$this.on('mouseenter', function () {
    var $this = $(this);

    $this.bind('mousewheel', function (e) {
        if ($list.is(':animated')) {
            return;
        }

        if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0) {
            direction = 1; //up
        } else {                
            direction = -1; //down
        }

        gotoSlide(direction);
    });
});
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#scroll').scroll();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lvd90p6j/

The problem is scrolling works properly only for the first element and doesn't work for other ones, although changing of the classes works the right way. What's the problem, how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to increment scroll depending on where current scroll is at. Right now you're reassigning without taking into consideration where you're at. Like this:

```
$list.animate({
            scrollTop: (direction === -1) ? $list.scrollTop()+scrollHeight : $list.scrollTop()-scrollHeight
        }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m5unj2wu/1/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that scrollHeight has always the same value.

Comment: Can you explain me how can I fix it, please?